# Outlook Web Add-in : second time click on Send button not triggering the 'event'

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an outlook 365 add-in and we came across an issue where 'Send' button does not triggers 'event' when clicking after an event.completed(true).

Following are the execution steps :

1. Add something in item.body using an UI less command button.
2. After completion of changes in item.body call Event.Completed({allowEvent : true }); so that event will be completed and no error will be displayed on UI.
3. Now click on 'Send' button which calls a function for 'send event'.

Is it a known bug or am I missing something? can anyone please guide me.

Note : I have made sure that On send feature is enabled and it is working fine if I do not call any 'event.completed()' prior to click on 'Send' button.

Comment: This is an Open Issue at OfficeDev : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/118 . Hope this will help someone to find alternate way to find  the solution for same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Open Issue at OfficeDev : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/118 . Hope this will help someone to find alternate way to find the solution for same issue.